# Tomcat startup fails due to 'java.net.SocketException Invalid argument' on Mac OS X

Tags: tomcat, java-native-interface, java

We have an application that runs on Tomcat 6 (6.0.35.0 to be precise), and most of our engineers on Mac OS are having problems starting Tomcat due to the socketAccept call in the Catalina.await method throwing a SocketException:

```
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: accept:
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:431)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:676)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:628)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
      at mycompany.tomcat.startup.ThreadDumpWrapper.main(ThreadDumpWrapper.java:260)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp.run(WrapperStartStopApp.java:238)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This causes Tomcat to shut down immediately after startup (and no small amount of rage). 
We think this has been with us for the duration on Mac OS w/ Java 1.7, in the last several months a lot of us have switched to Macbook Pros. Up until now, the only symptom was occasional zero byte responses from Tomcat, due to this exception also being thrown on a socketRead. Errors don't hit the logs and we'd individually shrugged it off as an isolated problem, and only found the cause when the startup problem started and I set a SocketException breakpoint:

```
Daemon Thread [http-8080-1] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 47 in SocketException))  
  SocketException.<init>(String) line: 47 
  SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available [native method] 
  SocketInputStream.socketRead0(FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) line: not available  
  SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) line: 150 
  SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) line: 121  
  InternalInputBuffer.fill() line: 735  
  InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine() line: 366  
  Http11Processor.process(Socket) line: 814 
  Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Socket) line: 602  
  JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 489  
  Thread.run() line: 722
```

For arguments:

```
arg0  FileDescriptor  (id=499)  
  fd  1097  
  useCount  AtomicInteger  (id=503) 
    value 2 
arg1  (id=502)
arg2  0 
arg3  8192  
arg4  20000
```

The problem is time sensitive. Increasing startup time due to application changes (lots more Spring introspection/singleton overhead) seems to be the factor that causes this to affect Tomcat startup; the tipping point being about 160 seconds. We can mitigate the problem by disabling some of the non-mandatory contexts we don't need during development to reduce startup time, but I'd prefer to find the root cause.

### Application configuration

The specifics of the application are far too complex to go into too much detail, but I have a hunch that this might relate to an earlier bind, so I'll at least list the listening ports on my machine:

```
localhost:32000 - Java service wrapper port
*:10001         - RMI registry
*:2322          - Java debug
*:56566         - RMI
*:8180          - Tomcat HTTP connector
*:8543          - Tomcat HTTPS connector
*:2223          - Tomcat Internal HTTP connector (used for cross-server requests)
*:14131         - 'Locking' port to determine if an internal service is running
*:56571         - EhCache RMI
*:56573         - RMI
*:62616         - ActiveMQ broker
*:5001          - SOAPMonitorService
*:8109          - Tomcat shutdown port
```

### Items ruled out

- The most obvious solution: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`. I've always had that option configured
- Any recent configuration change to our base application configuration, libraries, JVM options (there aren't any)
- A JDK regression. I've tested JDK 1.7.0_09, 11, 15, 17 and 21 (the JDKs I've had installed on my machine for the duration)
- Mac OS update. Mac OS 10.7.x and 10.8.0 through 1.8.3 are affected
- File descriptor limits - increased from `5000` to `10000`
- Disabling IPv6 completely on the main ethernet interface
- Setting breakpoints, and removing the first contexts to be affected by the SocketException (they're outgoing HTTP calls to web services). No change
- Configuring `/etc/hosts` so the machine hostname resolves to localhost, and configuring JVM options to prefer IPv4 and to *not* prefer IPv6 addresses (This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318860/364206)

For those interested in hosts configuration, it's the same as default. I can reproduce this on a Fusion VM w/ a clean install of 10.8:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

### Java code investigation

Due to the apparent time sensitive nature of the issue, setting breakpoints to troubleshoot the issue causes it to not occur. As requested in the comments, I also captured `arg0` for `SocksSocketImpl(PlainSocketImpl).socketAccept(SocketImpl)`, nothing seems out of the ordinary.

```
arg0  SocksSocketImpl  (id=460) 
  address InetAddress  (id=465) 
    canonicalHostName null  
    holder  InetAddress$InetAddressHolder  (id=475) 
      address 0 
      family  0 
      hostName  null  
  applicationSetProxy false 
  closePending  false 
  cmdIn null  
  cmdOut  null  
  cmdsock null  
  CONNECTION_NOT_RESET  0 
  CONNECTION_RESET  2 
  CONNECTION_RESET_PENDING  1 
  external_address  null  
  fd  FileDescriptor  (id=713)  
    fd  -1  
    useCount  AtomicInteger  (id=771) 
      value 0 
  fdLock  Object  (id=714)  
  fdUseCount  0 
  localport 0 
  port  0 
  resetLock Object  (id=716)  
  resetState  0 
  server  null  
  serverPort  1080  
  serverSocket  null  
  shut_rd false 
  shut_wr false 
  socket  Socket  (id=718)  
    bound false 
    closed  false 
    closeLock Object  (id=848)  
    connected false 
    created false 
    impl  null  
    oldImpl false 
    shutIn  false 
    shutOut false 
  socketInputStream null  
  stream  false 
  timeout 0 
  trafficClass  0 
  useV4 false
```

I think all of the threads where the exceptions are thrown are victims of an earlier call, one that doesn't result in a SocketException so I haven't been able to catch it. Being able to start Tomcat by reducing startup times convinces me that the trigger is probably some scheduled task that performs a socket based operation, which then affects other socket operations.

That doesn't explain how and why this could affect several threads, no matter what we're doing to cause this condition, mysterious SocketExceptions shouldn't bubble up from native code and cause these exceptions simultaneously on multiple threads - that is, two threads making outgoing web service calls, the Tomcat await call, and several TP processor threads repeatedly.

### JNI code investigation

Given the generic message, I assumed that an `EINVAL` error must be returned from one of the system calls in the socketAccept JNI code, so I traced the system calls leading up to the exception; there's no `EINVAL` returned from any system call. So, I went to the OpenJDK sources looking for conditions in the socketAccept code that would set and then throw an `EINVAL`, but I also couldn't find any code that sets `errno` to `EINVAL`, or calls `NET_ThrowByNameWithLastError`, `NET_ThrowCurrent` or `NET_ThrowNew` in a way that would throw a SocketException with this default error message.

As far as the system calls, we don't seem to get as far as the accept system call:

```
 PID/THRD        RELATIVE   ELAPSD    CPU SYSCALL(args)    = return
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538243       5      0 sigprocmask(0x1, 0x0, 0x14D8BE100)    = 0x0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538244       3      0 sigaltstack(0x0, 0x14D8BE0F0, 0x0)     = 0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538836      14     10 socket(0x2, 0x1, 0x0)    = 1170 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538837       3      0 fcntl(0x492, 0x3, 0x4)     = 2 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538839       3      1 fcntl(0x492, 0x4, 0x6)     = 0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538842       5      2 setsockopt(0x492, 0xFFFF, 0x4)     = 0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538852       7      4 bind(0x492, 0x14D8BE5D8, 0x10)     = 0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221538857       5      2 listen(0x492, 0x1, 0x4)    = 0 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221539625       6      2 psynch_cvsignal(0x7FEFBFE00868, 0x10000000200, 0x100)    = 257 0
 6606/0x2c750d:  221539633       4      1 write(0x2, "Apr 18, 2013 11:05:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await\nSEVERE: StandardServer.await: accept: \njava.net.SocketException: Invalid argument\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAcce", 0x644)    = 1604 0
```

So, I *think* the problem occurs in the timeout handling code at the top of the accept loop in `socketAccept`, but I couldn't find any case where `NET_Timeout` would set `errno` to `EINVAL`, and result in this SocketException being thrown. I'm referring to this code; I assume the jdk7u branch is for the most part what ships in the Oracle JDK:

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/d4bf5c15837c/src/solaris/native/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.c
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/d4bf5c15837c/src/solaris/native/java/net/bsd_close.c
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/d4bf5c15837c/src/solaris/native/java/net/net_util_md.c

### Help!

I can't find anyone in the outside world affected by this particular problem on Mac OS, but almost everyone here is affected. There must be some application configuration that contributes, but I've exhausted every avenue I can think of to find the root cause.

Pointers on troubleshooting or insight on a possible cause would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this exact same issue when starting up Tomcat on my Mac.  I also have a large web application (uPortal) that takes approx 100 seconds for Tomcat to startup.

Comment: Great to have a "me too". Surprisingly little chatter about this online.

Comment: Could you retrieve the values that are being passed to the native method and post here? It may lead to nowhere, but it's worth checking the arguments when you get an 'Invalid Argument' error :)

Comment: @cahen I've added details for arg0 for SocksSocketImpl(PlainSocketImpl).socketAccept(SocketImpl), but this exception can be thrown when apparently identical arguments are passed in

Comment: Having a similar issue. This crashes Eclipse - I have projects with a shitload of JARs in the dependencies (computed by plugin), and Eclipse keeps an open FD to each of them...

Comment: @DannyThomas May I ask you, why were you looking into `src/solaris/native` folder, while having a problem on Mac OSX? I'm currently searching for native sources for Mac, and I wonder if this is a right place?

Comment: @weekens not terribly familiar with the JDK structure, but it appears that's where the native code for BSD lives too. I noticed conditionals for Linux in this code too, so my assumption is that the Solaris sources are the base for all Unixes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried [turning on JNI debugging](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/jni_debug.html) with `-Xcheck:jni`?  Interestingly the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbmtq) uses a `PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept` error as an example of when to use this.

Note also that the implication of [Bug 7131399](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7131399) is that the JNI uses `poll()` on most platforms but `select()` on Mac OS due to a problem with `poll()` on the Mac.  So maybe `select()` is broken too.  Digging in a bit further, select() will return EINVAL if "ndfs is greater than FD_SETSIZE and _DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT is not defined." FD_SETSIZE is 1024 and it sounds like you have a ton of applications loading up, so perhaps it all filters down to waiting on more that 1024 FDs at one time.

For extra credit, see if [the related (supposedly fixed) Java bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7129798) is in fact fixed on your machine.  The bug report has pointers to test cases.

---

Thanks to Old Pro's answer, I confirmed that the `select()` FD_SETSIZE limitation is the cause. I located an existing bug for this limitation:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021820

The problem can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SelectTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Use 1024 file descriptors. There'll already be some in use, obviously, but this guarantees the problem will occur
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
      new FileInputStream("/dev/null");
    }
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    socket.accept();
  }
}
```

Almost a year later, Java 7u60 has a fix this problem:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/7u60-bugfixes-2202029.html

I also discovered the Tomcat's WebappClassLoader closes file handles after 90 seconds, which explains why setting break points prevented the issue from occurring.

Comment: I hadn't tried `-Xcheck:jni`. It makes startup take much much longer so the problem doesn't occur; I guess the causal and victim calls happen too far apart with this enabled. At least no problem was found with the individual JNI calls. I _had_ noticed that `select()` was used on Mac OS, it's noted prominently on `NET_Timeout` in `bsd_close.c`. I was going to try a JDK release that still used `poll()` to see if this maybe related to that change, but 7u5 was the first official Oracle JDK release for Mac OS and this was fixed in u4. I'll take a closer look at those test cases next week.

Comment: Digging in a bit further, `select()` will return EINVAL if "`ndfs` is greater than FD_SETSIZE and _DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT is not defined."  FD_SETSIZE is 1024 and it sounds like you have a ton of applications loading up, so perhaps it all filters down to waiting on more that 1024 FDs at one time.

Comment: Now _that's_ a distinct possibility! Class loader activity from Spring alone could maybe cause that. Very promising lead.

Comment: It would explain why it is timing-sensitive and make stagger-starting the correct solution.

Comment: ...and the use of select over poll why this is Mac OS specific.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in 7u60. Doesn't seem to have a release date yet but early access builds are available at https://jdk7.java.net/download.html

Comment: The [select FD_SETSIZE limitation bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021820) referenced here is marked fixed in JDK 8, but, as for sigget, upgrading to the early access [JDK 7u60](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html) resolves this issue for me. If you're running into intermittent `SocketException`s on OS X and you're not making lots of connections, give 7u60 a try.

Comment: I got this error while trying to connect VisualVM on 7u51 but issue seems to be fixed already on latest release 7u55.

Comment: elasticsearch 1.4.0 suffers this issue as well

Comment: Well holy crap, I've run into the same issue and upgrading to u75 fixed it. I believe this is still the only resource that properly explains the issue and its solution - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue (with Tomcat7), and what seems to work for me is to tick the "Publish module contexts to separate XML files" option when I'm running tomcat inside Eclipse. Have you tried that already?

Comment: We do configure contexts in server.xml, there are 51 contexts configured statically. We have another 80 or so more, deployed dynamically by our plugin framework. This sounds more akin to our workaround, than a cause. Do you have any information on why this makes a difference? Do you see the zero-byte response issues?

Answer (score 1):

Get OpenJDK with the fix:

http://www.java.net/download/jdk7u60/archive/b15/binaries/jdk-7u60-ea-bin-b15-macosx-x86_64-16_apr_2014.dmg

Worked for me!

Comment: This update won't run on OSX Yosemite. See https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_10_10.xml . Use 7u71 or 7u72 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling with this problem in another context. Solution(s) combined from different sources look like next:

- Update /etc/hosts with next overrides:

  - ::1            EWD-MacBook-Pro.local
  - 127.0.0.1      EWD-MacBook-Pro.local localhost

(EWD-MacBook-Pro.local is my machine name)

***and***

- Set system properties:

  - java.net.preferIPv4Stack  =>  true
  - java.net.preferIPv6Addresses => false

Good luck!

Comment: Promising answer, but no luck I'm afraid :(