# Why doesn't dtruss show me the select system call in this JNI code?

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface

While investigating this JDK bug on Mac OS, I ran into system call trace output I don't understand:

[Tomcat startup fails due to 'java.net.SocketException Invalid argument' on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191236/tomcat-startup-fails-due-to-java-net-socketexception-invalid-argument-on-mac-o)

The short version: On Mac OS, the JDK uses `select()` instead of `poll()`. So, if more than 1024 file descriptors are allocated, we deduced that the `select()` call in `NET_Timeout` fails resulting in a SocketException with an 'Invalid argument' message. However, when I traced the system calls, I saw no evidence of the `select()` system call, or any call that fails and sets EINVAL, so I discounted that as a potential cause.

I also don't see the call with the reduced test case I've created now I understand the problem:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class SelectTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
      new FileInputStream("/dev/null");
    }
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    socket.accept();
  }
}
```

Results in this exception on Mac OS w/ JDK 1.7u5 and later:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at SelectTest.main(SelectTest.java:12)
```

Why don't I see any evidence of the `select()` (or any other failing) call when I run the test using `sudo dtruss -a java SelectTest`?

```
        PID/THRD  RELATIVE  ELAPSD    CPU SYSCALL(args)                  = return
45563/0x63a513:     85544       6      4 bind(0x412, 0x10DFC7738, 0x1C)          = 0 0
45563/0x63a513:     85605       6      3 listen(0x412, 0x32, 0x32)               = 0 0
45563/0x63a513:     85619       2      0 lseek(0x4, 0x37377AD, 0x0)              = 57898925 0
45563/0x63a513:     85622       4      2 read(0x4, "PK\003\004\n\0", 0x1E)               = 30 0
45563/0x63a513:     85622       1      0 lseek(0x4, 0x37377E0, 0x0)              = 57898976 0
45563/0x63a513:     85627       5      4 read(0x4, "\312\376\272\276\0", 0x3447)                 = 13383 0
45563/0x63a513:     86150      37     33 write(0x2, "Exception in thread \"main\" ble\001\0", 0x1B)              = 27 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect `ServerSocket.accept` to call exactly what you saw.

The Berkeley sockets calls corresponding to Java's `accept` are [listen()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) and [accept()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept)

Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce the exception on linux. If I use all the fd's before `new ServerSocket(8080)` I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.<clinit>(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:80)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.setImpl(ServerSocket.java:289)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:230)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
    at SelectTest.main(SelectTest.java:15)
```

Comment: In this case the problem isn't hitting the cd limit, it's using more than 1024 with select call, which is in the network timeout handling code for Darwin (bsd_close.c). See the linked question for details - it's Darwin specific.