# Can not get proper response from select() using writefds

Tags: linux, select

Parent receives SIGPIPE sending chars to aborted child process through FIFO pipe.
I am trying to avoid this, using select() function. In the attached sample code,
select() retruns OK even after the child at the other end of pipe having been terminated.
Tested in
    RedHat EL5 （Linux 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5）
    GNU C Library stable release version 2.5
Any help appreciated. Thnak you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sigpipe_fct();

main()
{
struct stat st;
int  i, fd_out, fd_in, child;
char buf[1024];
#define p_out "/tmp/pout"

    signal(SIGPIPE, sigpipe_fct);

    if (stat(p_out, &st) != 0)  {
        mknod(p_out, S_IFIFO, 0);
        chmod(p_out, 0666);
    }
    /* start receiving process */
    if ((child = fork()) == 0)  {
        if ((fd_in = open(p_out, O_RDONLY)) < 0)  {
            perror(p_out);
            exit(1);
        }
        while(1)  {
           i = read(fd_in, buf, sizeof(buf));
           fprintf(stderr, "child %d read %.*s\n", getpid(), i, buf);
           lseek(fd_in, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    else  {
        fprintf(stderr,
           "reading from %s - exec \"kill -9 %d\" to test\n", p_out, child);
        if ((fd_out = open(p_out, O_WRONLY + O_NDELAY)) < 0) { /*  output */
            perror(p_out);
            exit(1);
        }
        while(1)  {
            if (SelectChkWrite(fd_out) == fd_out)  {
                fprintf(stderr, "SelectChkWrite() success write abc\n");
                write(fd_out, "abc", 3);
            }
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "SelectChkWrite() failed\n");
            sleep(3);
        }
    }
}

static void sigpipe_fct()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "SIGPIPE received\n");
    exit(-1);
}

SelectChkWrite(ch)
int ch;
{
#include <sys/select.h>
fd_set  writefds;
int     i;

    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_SET (ch, &writefds);

    i = select(ch + 1, NULL, &writefds, NULL, NULL);

    if (i == -1)
        return(-1);
    else if (FD_ISSET(ch, &writefds))
        return(ch);
    else
        return(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Linux [`select(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select):

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for writing when a call to an
>   output function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not
>   the function would transfer data successfully.

When the pipe is closed, it won't block, so it is considered "ready" by `select`.

BTW, having `#include <sys/select.h>` *inside* your `SelectChkWrite()` function is extremely bad form.

Although `select()` and [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) are both in the POSIX standard, `select()` is much older and more limited than `poll()`. In general, I recommend people use `poll()` by default and only use `select()` if they have a good reason.  (See here for [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352837/712765).)

Comment: Thanks for a prompt answer. I found out that I should be using

Comment: poll() instead of select(). Poll() fits to my need completely.