# GridGain 6.2.0 / 6.2.1 : too many file descriptors open

Tags: linux, macos, gridgain

After upgrading to gridgain 6.2.0, on mac and linux we get "too many open files" exceptions when running our junit test case suite. The individual test cases run fine on their. We get these errors  only when we run the entire suite. Has anything changed in the number of files gridgain keeps open in 6.2.x? Here is an example of the exception on Mac (On linux, the error is similar but stems from the nio package). Increasing the open file limit addresses on the OS resolves the issue but is this issue a bug or just an additional upgrade item to be noted?

Thanks

```
[2014-09-10 12:02:49,396] ERROR GridTcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to accept TCP connection
On MAC OS you may have too many file descriptors open (simple restart usually solves the issue) []
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi$TcpServer.body(GridTcpDiscoverySpi.java:5037)
at org.gridgain.grid.spi.GridSpiThread.run(GridSpiThread.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From which version of GridGain are you upgrading to 6.2.1? Most likely this error is caused by shared memory communication between nodes on one host. It can be fixed by increasing the open files limit in operation system, or by switching shared memory off. Can you check if your exception is reproduced without shared memory? To switch it off configure communication SPI like this:

```
<property name="communicationSpi">
    <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.communication.tcp.GridTcpCommunicationSpi">
        <property name="sharedMemoryPort" value="-1"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: We're upgrading from 6.1.6 . Turning off shared memory like you suggested worked. Thanks! 
Is there any downside to this solution (we use gridgain mostly for grid job distribution across a cluster i.e. cpu intensive work) ?

Comment: Also, I noticed that configuring the communication SPI like you suggests gets rid of the following log warning. This is expected since we the configuration disables shared memory. That said, is this a recommended configuration? I read the reference at http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/GridTcpCommunicationSpi .Thanks


`[2014-09-11 11:02:49,578] WARN  GridTcpCommunicationSpi - Failed to start shared memory communication server. []`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the question is a duplicate of [Tomcat startup fails due to 'java.net.SocketException Invalid argument' on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191236/tomcat-startup-fails-due-to-java-net-socketexception-invalid-argument-on-mac-o) .
As I understand, the solution is to upgrade JDK to 7u60 or above, at least that works for us.
(Our experiments have shown that on MacOs even significant increase of open files limit does not resolve the problem.)